# Double define kubernetesPodUtils

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to do a Spring Boot app deployed on GKE. It uses an application.yml file. I use a K8s configmap to map the dev/stage/prod file as needed. Spring sees it as a normal app, not a k8s app.

I have a configmap and a secret. Do I need a discoveryClient? Do I need all of Fabric? Basicall I want to read the secret as though it were a property in application.yml

I added

spring-cloud-kubernetes-autoconfig and
spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-all
spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons

and now it's trying to double define 'kubernetesPidUtils'. I have no explicit reference to this nor do I know if I need it.

My configmap defines
spring.application.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.name and namespace.

Comment: I've had success mounting the ConfigMap as an ordinary file and setting `$SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` to point there.  That doesn't require any specific Kubernetes support in the application.  What have you tried so far, and what trouble are you running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm already doing what you suggest. I'm trying to move tokens out of the configmap. I got that part, just want Spring to read them like it would a property out of application.yml

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]?  I'm a little unclear what specific problem you're running into.  If the ConfigMap doesn't contain a Spring properties file as a single value, the other obvious approach is to load environment variables from the ConfigMap.  The Spring Boot documentation on [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) describes all of the places Spring looks for configuration (without a specific Kubernetes integration) and you might be able to map that to your setup.